# Single grouping, multi selection. Sub query required?

Tags: postgresql

Data can be created by the below:

```
create table rows (
  client_tracking_id text,
  external_id text,
  transaction_date timestamp,
  transaction_type text,
  transaction_amount numeric(18,2)
);

INSERT INTO rows 
VALUES ('281101002240', '281101002240','2019-08-14 18:03:04.000000'::timestamp,'Purchase',2000), 
('RC000610808201930230', '281101002240','2019-08-19 07:56:45.000000'::timestamp,'AuthorizationRequest',0),
('RC000610808201930230', '281101002240','2019-08-19 07:56:46.000000'::timestamp,'AuthorizationRequest',-2000),
('RC000610808201930230', '281101002240','2019-08-19 07:56:46.000000'::timestamp,'Purchase',-2000);
```

Where the goal of this query is to retrieve the datetime of the first (positive) purchase but to return the RC value of the client_tracking_id column.

Attempt 1:

```
SELECT max(client_tracking_id) AS client_tracking_id,
       min(transaction_date)   AS min
from rows
GROUP BY external_id;
```

Attempt 2:

```
SELECT max(client_tracking_id) AS client_tracking_id,
       min(transaction_date)   AS min
from rows
where (transaction_type = 'Purchase'::text) AND (transaction_amount > (0)::numeric)
GROUP BY external_id;
```

Where attempt one works for this specific case correctly returning the set of `[RC00061080820193023,'2019-08-14 18:03:04.000000']` however this is not always true in other cases. Thus the additional requirement that the datetime being returned as only the transaction which meets the where criteria in attempt two.

Available on SQL Fiddle at: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/642fd/6

Comment: `but to return the RC value of the client_tracking_id column` what RC value? You have 2 what is the logic to select the RC ?

Answer (score 0):

First you filter, you only want 'Purchase' > 0. Then just sort by date and take the earliest one.

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/642fd/7)**

```
select * 
from rows
WHERE transaction_amount > 0 
  AND transaction_type = 'Purchase'
ORDER BY transaction_date 
LIMIT 1
;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| client_tracking_id |  external_id |     transaction_date | transaction_type | transaction_amount |
|--------------------|--------------|----------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|       281101002240 | 281101002240 | 2019-08-14T18:03:04Z |         Purchase |               2000 |
```

Comment: I answer what you put as `goal` in the question. But just realize that isn't related to the title, so I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: Juan, thank you for the quick response. That is the correct transaction yes, but it needs to be "associated" with the RC "Id" values that are only in the later transactions. Again, I'm looking to get to the response of `[RC00061080820193023,'2019-08-14 18:03:04.000000']`

Comment: Sorry dont understand what you mean by RC?  or later transaction. Do you have extra table not included in the question?

Comment: You need to explain what is the logic a litle more. Remember we dont have a background of your problem. So we only can answer what you ask.

Comment: Absolutely! client_tracking_id is supposed to contain all values beginning with "RC..." however, in this case the first transaction was overwritten by the value of the external_id column "281101002240". (All the values of the client_tracking_id column should be identical but are not) That is why I am looking a query to work around that constraint.

Comment: That doesnt explain the logic. How I know what is overwritten or what choose

Answer (score 0):

I've developed the following to meet all my requirements:

```
select distinct
(
  select max(client_tracking_id) as id
  from rows r1
  where r1.external_id = r.external_id
) as client_tracking_id,
(
select min(transaction_date) as date
from rows r2
WHERE transaction_type = 'Purchase' AND transaction_amount > 0
and r2.external_id = r.external_id
) as date

from rows r
```